# can i build apps with ionic using angular version 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to know that can i use ionic with angular version 1 to builds App.
If yes than which  version of ionic  will matter in that case, means which version  of ionic  have to use with angular version 1.
Can i use the latest ionic version with angular version 1.I searched out but did not find any detail answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic V1 docs supports angular version1. You need to install the Ionic version 2.2.1 and you can use the ionic framework docs v1 in your application with angular 1.

```
npm install -g ionic@2.2.1
```

use this command to install ionic.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for answer..
so is it not possible to use ionic latest version? with angular version 1?

Comment: yes it's not possible to use angular version 1 in ionic latest version. Because Ionic latest version supports Typescript where Angular 1 uses Javascript..